# React передача пропсов от соседнего компонента к соседнему

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Мне надо передать определённые данные в соседний компонент, то есть не от родителя к дочернему, а от соседнего к соседнему

Comment: тогда в родителе надо добавить стейт и изменять его из чайлдов, либо юзать контекст

Comment: [подъем состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)